# PHP, MYSQL -Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

¡Buenas noches!

Tengo un error con una consulta en Mysql, y le estoy dando vueltas y no lo veo, a ver si me pueden ayudar.

El error es :

> Trying to get property of non-object

Se que el error viene de la consulta.

he probado con :

```
$comp2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = '".$d."' WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ");
```

tambien con:

```
$comp2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = '".$d."' WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' and NRecogida = '".$a_comp['NRecogida']."' ");
```

además con :

```
$comp2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = '0' WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ");
```

y con :

```
$comp2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = 0 WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ");
```

Pero ninguna opción da resultado.

Cosas a tener en cuenta es que : `$d = '0'` (tambien he probado con `$d = 0` y nada)

que enlace tiene dos claves externas que además son sus claves primarias llamadas `NEntrega` y `NRecogida` , además tiene una columna dias de tipo int.

`a_comp['NRecogida']` es de una consulta anterior que sale bien.

y `$num` es un parámetro que pasamos a la función.

Gracias de antemano.

El codigo completo es:

```
function Pagar($conexion,$num){
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM albaran WHERE NumAlbaran = '".$num."' ");
    if($res->num_rows > 0){
        $daux = new DateTime('NOW');
        $daux2 = $daux->format('Y-m-d');
        $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE albaran SET fecha_pagado = '".$daux2."' WHERE NumAlbaran = '".$num."' ");
        if(!$res2){
            echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong> No se ha podido pagar. </strong>
            </div></td></tr>";
        }
        else{
            $comp = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM enlace WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ");
            //pagamos uno que ya hemos recogido y se pasó de dias
            if($comp->num_rows > 0){
                $d = 0;
                $a_comp =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($comp);
                $comp2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = '".$d."' WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ");
                echo $comp2;
                if($comp2 && ($comp2->num_rows > 0)){
                    echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <strong> PAGADO </strong>
                    </div></td></tr>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <strong> No se ha podido pagar bien. </strong>
                    </div></td></tr>";
                }
            }
            else{
                //no tenia enlace pero ha pagado
                echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-success'>
                    <strong> PAGADO </strong>
                </div></td></tr>";
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <strong> No se ha podido pagar. </strong>
        </div></td></tr>";
    }
    unset($_POST['Pay']);
    unset($_POST['NumPay']);
}
```

Comment: pon el demás código que uses ya que por ejemplo el error te lo da al querer usar una variable como objeto cuando no lo es, cosa que en estas lineas no haces

Comment: si puedes, ademas de lo que dice @Sr1871, comprueba si la query te da error, pues puede ser que la consulta este dando error y luego estes tratando de realizar alguna accion con $comp2. prueba con; if (!mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = '".$d."' WHERE NEntrega = '".$num."' ")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
} y revisa si te da un error.

Comment: En MySQL pruebe las consultas, EJ: en SQL dentro de MySQL agregar "UPDATE enlace SET enlace.dias = 0 WHERE NEntrega = 123; Si le da error, es porque la consulta está mal, si no el error está dentro del código en PHP.

Comment: Acabo de poner todo el código de la función, voy a probar en el simulador de MySQL @JulianPerez

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que  UPDATE devuelve solo true o false, no se pueden ver las líneas, ¡gracias a todos!

Comment: Para `UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE` debes usar `affected_rows` si quieres saber la cantidad de filas afectadas por la consulta.